# Detecting wifi devices around me with android

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

Is there a way I can detect all Wifi devices arround me and get signal strength from android device.

For experimental use, I would like to run an app on some android device. the app should record signal strength  between each phone and the others.
I would like the "connection" to be directly between the phone, without using an external router.
I believe this is possible as android phone has the ability to function as Wifi router, so it may be detected by other devices. But I have no idea how to programmatically approach this.

Can anyone help?
Do you think this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scan all the wifi nearby, try this

Create a wifiManager,BroadcastReceiver, and scan all the wifi using any async task, the result of scanning will get on the broadcast receiver

```
WifiManager wManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
// wifi Scan
    new wifiScan().execute(); // call to async task

    BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
    wifiList = wManager.getScanResults();

    for (int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++) {
    ScanResult scanresult = wManager.getScanResults().get(i);
    ssid = scanresult.SSID;//ssid is Name of wifi (String)
    bid = scanresult.BSSID;// bssid: MAC of wifi (String)
    level = scanresult.level;//level: strength of wifi(int)
        }

        };



// Async task

public class wifiScan extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
        int i = 0;

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void results) {
         if (results != null) { if (i < 6) { new wifiScan().execute(); 
                     }
                  }


    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(
                WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        wManager.startScan();
        return null;
    }
}
```

You'll be able to communicate between two devices over wifi without a router/access point using [Wifi Direct (P2P)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/package-summary.html).
I think this features can access from Android 4.0., Otherwise, I am not sure.